# Creating Pivot Table with data having multiple variables

Tags: excel, pivot-table

This is how my raw data looks:
[image]

I want to create a Pivot Table that summarises this (currently made using COUNTIF):
[image]

This is my progress with the Pivot Table:
[image]

The data gets cluttered if I add all 5 subjects/courses to the "Rows" in the Pivot Table. If I keep only one of the five subjects in the "Rows" of the Pivot Table, the count is correctly displayed for only that particular subject.

How do I make it possible?

Comment: You want that 'Confidence level of Students' will it show in the order you show in your first table?

Comment: I want the frequency distribution table to be created as shown in the second image, however, while trying to create using pivot table, I'm getting the third image as my output.

Answer (score 0):

You must define a custom sorting list:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can then select this list to sort your pivot table.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Good luck!